# How to create new files in my external slot SDCARD ( its not in internal storage) - "/mnt/sdcard2/"

Tags: android, directory, storage, sd-card

my question is I need to use files from my external slot sdcard, please dont suggest me to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` - it is for internal storage 
I wanted to created files in external storage

Comment: [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29). That is not internal storage like you told. If you fixed directory like that, there's will be error on many device. For example : NexusS is `/mnt/sdcard/` or Samsung is `/sdcard/external_sd/`

Comment: @Yul- Did you try it practically? When I use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), it creates a file in my internal storage i.e.. /mnt/sdcard/- This is the internal storage.

Comment: There are three concerns here: identifying the device- and version- specific location, having permission to write to it, and correctly implementing the file operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its possible. When I was working on my own app I encountered the same problem if there is internal writable memory. Searched for days trying to find out how how to get the actual external SD card but no luck.

I thinks its because the way android uses storage, the internal sd card is called SDCARD and the external one is linked to SDCARD0 (or something similar can't remember at the top of my head). When you run getExternalStorage it just looks for SDCARD and goes to the internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
File myFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard2/myFile");
```

**Edit :**
forgot to mention that you have to create the file:

```
boolean fileCreated = myFile.createNewFile();
//at this point fileCreated must be true and the file must exists on your sdcard2
```

**Edit :**

From File.createNewFile() javadoc:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @return true if the file has been created, false if it
 *         already exists.
 * @throws IOException if it's not possible to create the file.
 */
```

So either, the file is created, either it already exists, either you got an IOException... or your code didn't call createNewFile() ...

Comment: File newFile= new File("/mnt/sdcard2/myFile"); 
try {
        newFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    
    Log.d(TAG, "file exception: "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
   }

Comment: I did not get any error, and also file is not created in sdcard2

Comment: and what's the return value of createNewFile ?

Comment: It says true and  path is /mnt/sdcard2/myFile, value is also shown right. But when I see in my device I cannot find that file

Comment: I got to know that we do not have write access to the external sd card slot one.