# I can't write to /mnt/sdcard2 in Android

Tags: java, android, ioexception, android-external-storage

Now I'm making some version of File Manager in Andoid. 
My permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

When I write new file to  ***/mnt/sdcard*** (External Stroage) everything is allright.
But When i write new file to ***/mnt/sdcard2*** (internal storage) I get IOException like
**open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**
My full code:

```
try {
            File existingFile = new File(path);
            File newFile = new File(newPath);
            if (!newFile.exists()) {
                if (!isFolder)
                {
                    newFile.createNewFile();
                }

            } 

            if (isFolder) {
                FileUtils.copyDirectory(existingFile, newFile);
            }
            else
            {
                FileUtils.copyFile(existingFile, newFile);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = 1;
        }
```

When i test my application I use real device.
My Path is like '/mnt/sdcard/Music/blabla' and so on

Comment: Which version's your android device?

Comment: Does `/mnt/sdcard2` exist?

Comment: `/mnt/sdcard2` exists and I worked with this folder. It is internal storage for my device. I can copy files from `/mnt/sdcard2` to `/mnt/sdcard`.

Comment: `if (!newFile.exists()) {
                if (!isFolder)
                {
                    newFile.createNewFile();
                }

            } `. You better remove all that code as it should not be needed as copyFile() should create the file. Moreover we cannot see how you initialize `isFolder`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935584/how-to-create-new-files-in-my-external-slot-sdcard-its-not-in-internal-storage  - the same problem

Answer (score 1):

> My Path is like '/mnt/sdcard/Music/blabla'

Do **not** use hardcoded paths as these may (and will) differ depending on device model or can even OS version. You got methods in [Environment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) class to get you root folder of external storage and you should use it like [getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

**EDIT**

> . I need to get folder that contents folder like Music, DCIM, Download, but in Inner Storage of Smartphone

You cannot have "private" DCIM, Downloads really if you want to use system features like DownloadManager or external Camera app, because these apps will simply not be able to write to your private storage. So you either download/take photo yourself - then you can save the file whenever you want, or you use what is it now available, with all the pros and cons.

Name "external"/"internal" is a bit misleading nowadays, so do not take it too literally.

Comment: **getExternalStorageDirectory()** returns me ExternalStorage. How can I get **Internal storage**?

Comment: you asked about SD card. This used to be **external** storage. See [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) methods for internal ones

Comment: `How can I get Internal storage?`. getFilesDir().

Comment: So.. . `getFilesDir()`  gives me my application folder like data/data/myApplication). I need to  get folder that contents folder like Music, DCIM, Download, but in Inner Storage of Smartphone. See this http://i1.wp.com/androidpicks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/File-Commander-Screenshot-New-Android-Picks.png

Comment: And I want to work with Internal storage, but what is absolute path for this?

Comment: `I need to get folder that contents folder like Music, DCIM, Download, `. Well then use getExternalStorageDirectory() or getExternalPublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).